What is the smallest area of a central section of the unit hypercube?
Let $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the unit hypercube i.e. $\mathcal{U} = [0,1]^n$, and assume that for some $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ one denotes by
$$
\mathcal{H} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | d^T\cdot \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1_{n \times 1}\right) = 0  \right\}
$$ a hyperplane passing through the center of the hyper-cube. I am interested in the minimum area of $\mathcal{H} \cap \mathcal{U}$. I know from literature that the maximum area of a general intersection between a hyperplane and the unit hypercube is $\sqrt{2}$ see here.
However, my question is about the smallest area of a hyperplane which is restricted to contain the center of the unit hypercube. I somehow think that this is 1 ( one ). Any section parallel with the faces, as well as some rotations of it, generates a section area of 1 ( one ) or greater, but I cannot prove the general case!
Clarification
This question has also been posted on Math Stack Exchange without an answer for several days. However, user X-Rui pointed out that the question is addressed in the linked literature, Theorem 2 page 3. Indeed, this is true, but upon looking at the proof I noticed that it is probabilistic. Regarding that I have the following observations:

I cannot understand if that proof prohibits the existence of any central section with an area less than $1$ ( one ), or just states that the number of such sections are of zero measure, therefore allowing perhaps an (countable) infinit number of counter-examples
Is there a proof of this statement which is not probabilistic ?


Here one can view the MSE version of the question. @C Marius it is a convention to wait at least a week between posting the same question on MSE and MO: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4969485/what-is-the-smallest-area-of-a-central-section-of-the-unit-hypercube

@MaxMuller I did not know the amount of time! I did know about several days though! I am sorry for my ignorance!

@C Marius it's alright, you're a relatively new user - just good to keep in mind for next time!

The smallest area is $1$. Is not this evident?

@AlexandreEremenko as can be seen in the Clarification section, it was not clear to me that the smallest area is $1$ for all the central sections.

As in the linked paper by K. Ball, it is more convenient to deal with the cube $Q:=[-1/2,1/2]^n$ instead of $\mathcal U$.
In Ball's paper, $f(r)$ is defined, for real $r$, as the volume of the intersection of $Q$ with a hyperplane parallel to a hyperplane $H$ and at distance $|r|$ from $H$. In particular, $f(0)$ is the volume of the intersection of $Q$ with $H$.
In the proof of Theorem 2 of Ball's paper, it is shown that $f(0)>1$ if $H$ is not parallel to any face of $Q$. This follows from the following facts:

In view of the Brunn--Minkowski inequality, $f(0)\ge f(r)$ for real $r$. Therefore and because $f$ is a nonnegative continuous function, we have $\|f\|_\infty=f(0)$.

By Lemma 1 in Ball's paper, $\|f\|_\infty\,\|X\|_2>\frac1{2\sqrt3}$, where $X$ is a certain non-uniformly distributed random variable with density $f$, whereas $\|X\|_2=\frac1{2\sqrt3}$.



Since $f(0)=1$ if $H$ is parallel to some face of $Q$, it follows that the minimal volume of the intersection of $Q$ with a hyperplane is $1$, and the minimum value $1$ is attained iff $H$ is parallel to some face of $Q$.
There is nothing in this proof involving sets of zero measure.

It seems that $f(r) = |(H+r\cdot a) \cap Q_n|$ is also the p.d.f of the random variable $X = \sum a_i \cdot X_i$ where $X_i$ are random variables uniformly distributed in $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$. I understood that indeed $f(0) \geq f(r)$ for all $r\geq 0$. This is indeed non-probabilistic and used Brun-Minkovski results for volumes. However, I guess that $E X_1^2 = \frac{1}{12}$ by Lemma 1  because it is uniformly distributed hence its p.d.f. is constant.

It is still not very clear to me that this proof prohibits the existence of counterexamples ... perhaps I have to think more ... Probably I have to rewrite everything there with another language to avoid probabilities entirely ...

It is indeed straightforward to rewrite everything here in a non-probabilistic way. In particular, the expectations can be rewritten as $n$-fold integrals. The probabilistic language here is just for convenience.

While the proof in Ball's paper Cube Slicing in $\mathbb{R}^n$ uses probability theory, the result is deterministic. It is proved that the function $f(t) = |(H+ta)\cap Q|$ (where $H$ is the hyperplane through the midpoint of the cube $Q$ and $a$ is a unit normal vector to $H$) has minimum value at $t=0$ for all $a$ with $\|a\|_\infty<1$. By continuity this shows that the minimal cross section appears for $a = e_i$ and $t=0$.

Actually I can see that the paper says $f(0) \geq f(r)$ (i.e. maximum at $t = 0$ ) then they show $|f|{\infty} \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \geq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$ which gives $f(0) \geq 1$ because $f(0) = |f|{\infty}$. The part with $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$ thou is probabilistic and I am not yet convinced ... I have to think more

That "probabilistic" part is really the value of an expectation (iirc) and this is an integral.
